# Заменить текст в виджете корзины

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести свой текст в виджете корзине в шапке (например, "Корзина пуста"), вместо "0 товаров в корзине"?

```
function yit_get_current_cart_info() {

    $items = yit_get_option( 'shop-mini-cart-total-items' ) ? WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() : count( WC()->cart->get_cart() );
    $total = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();

    return array(
        sprintf( _n( '1 товар в корзине', '%s товаров в корзине', $items, 'yit' ), $items ),
        $total
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если этот код рабочий и задача в том, чтобы его изменить, то так:

```
function yit_get_current_cart_info() {

    $items = yit_get_option( 'shop-mini-cart-total-items' ) ? WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() : count( WC()->cart->get_cart() );
    $total = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();

    if ( 0 === $items ) {
        return array(
            'Корзина пуста',
            0,
        );
    } else {
        return array(
            sprintf( _n( '1 товар в корзине', '%s товаров в корзине', $items, 'yit' ), $items ),
            $total,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Понял причину. $items - не массив, а уже число товаров в корзине. Поправил код.